# Slider opens on every url of my catalog in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, slider, conflict, catalog

i am creating a Wordpress website and i have an irritating thing i want to get rid of.

In my product page i am using SmartSlider plugin to create a slider and also beyond it i am using another plugin called Ultimate Product Catalog for my product catalog. The thing is that when you click on Category it loads another Url on the same page, hence the slider remains on the page. Then when clicked the subcategory the same thing happens.

I want the slider to be only on the https://www.vista-in.com/products/ url not on every other,
for example here: https://www.vista-in.com/products/?categories=3

So can i change the appearance of the slider based on the url?

Any ideas?

Comment: you apply the if condition on your code in file with specific page id like is_page( 42 )  - When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed. You can get more details from this link - https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately not quite familiar with how to code wordpress websites and more specifically when used plugins.. :/